# How to get spark executor core id programatically

Tags: apache-spark

How to get spark executor core id programatically, is it available in SparkContext/SparkEnv. I do not want number of cores set for spark job, when my code is being executed by one of the core, I would like to get that core identity/name.

Comment: you mean the processor ID on which a current task is running?

Comment: Yes, I would like to make use of core-id to append to a string, and that string would be used for create a new file with that name.

Comment: it's not really a Spark problem - actually on the JVM it's not that easy to get the underlying CPU id... You would need to use JNI/JNA to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68079180/how-to-get-the-taskid-or-mapperidsomething-like-partitionid-in-spark-in-a-hive/