# How to get the taskID or mapperID(something like partitionID in Spark) in a hive UDF?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, mapreduce, user-defined-functions

As question, How to get the taskID or mapperID(something like partitionID in Spark) in a  hive UDF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the correct answer on my own, we can get the taskID in a hive UDF the way as below :

```
public class TestUDF extends GenericUDF  {
    private Text result = new Text();
    private String tmpStr = "";

    @Override
    public void configure(MapredContext context) {
        //get the number of tasks 获取task总数量
        int numTasks = context.getJobConf().getNumMapTasks();
        //get the current taskID 获取当前taskID
        String taskID =  context.getJobConf().get("mapred.task.id");
        this.tmpStr = numTasks + "_h_xXx_h_" + taskID;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arguments)
            throws UDFArgumentException {
        return PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments) {
        result.set(this.tmpStr);
        return this.result;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayString(String[] children) {
        return "RowSeq-func()";
    }
}
```

but this would be effective only in MapReduce execution engine, it would not work in a SparkSQL engine.
Test code as below:

```
add jar hdfs:///home/dp/tmp/shaw/my_udf.jar;
create temporary function seqx AS 'com.udf.TestUDF';

with core as (
select 
    device_id
from
    test_table
where
    p_date = '20210309' 
    and product = 'google'
distribute by
    device_id
)
select
    seqx() as seqs,
    count(1) as cc
from
    core
group by
    seqx()
order by
    seqs asc
```

Result in MR engine as below, see we have got the task number and taskID successfully:
[image]

Result in Spark engine with same sql above, the UDF is not valid, we get nothing about taskID:
[image]

If you run your HQL in Spark engine and call the Hive UDF meanwhile, and really need to get the partitionId in Spark, see the code below :

```
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext;

public class TestUDF extends GenericUDF  {
    private Text result = new Text();
    private String tmpStr = "";

    @Override
    public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arguments)
            throws UDFArgumentException {
        //get spark partitionId
        this.tmpStr = TaskContext.getPartitionId() + "-initial-pid";
        return PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector;
    }

    public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments) {
        //get spark partitionId
        this.tmpStr = TaskContext.getPartitionId() + "-evaluate-pid";
        result.set(this.tmpStr);
        return this.result;
    }
}
```

As above, you can get the Spark partitionId by calling `TaskContext.getPartitionId()` in the override method `initialize` or `evalute` of UDF class.
Notice: your UDF must has params, suchs `select my_udf(param)`, this would lead your UDF initialized in multiple tasks, if your UDF do not have a param, it will be initialized at the Driver, and the Driver do not have the taskContext and partitionId, so you would get nothing.

The image below is a result produced by the above UDF executed in Spark engine，see, we get the partitionIds successfully :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can access task information using TaskContext:

```
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext
sc.parallelize(Seq[Int](), 4).mapPartitions(_ => {
  val ctx = TaskContext.get
  val stageId = ctx.stageId
  val partId = ctx.partitionId
  val hostname = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
  Iterator(s"Stage: $stageId, Partition: $partId, Host: $hostname")}).collect.foreach(println)
```

A similar functionality has been added to PySpark in Spark 2.2.0 (SPARK-18576):

```
from pyspark import TaskContext
import socket

def task_info(*_):
    ctx = TaskContext()
    return ["Stage: {0}, Partition: {1}, Host: {2}".format 
    (ctx.stageId(), ctx.partitionId(), socket.gethostname())]

for x in sc.parallelize([], 4).mapPartitions(task_info).collect():
    print(x)
```

I think it will provide you the information about the task including map id you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I have known how to get partitionID in Spark, but my question is how to get taskID in Hive UDF.